# Explorer link (Shortcut) to SharePoint 2013 not working directly after a restart

Tags: 2013, open-with-explorer, network-drive

I we experiencing a strange behavior on our SharePoint 2013 Platform. If a user uses the `Library` > `Open with Explorer` on any various folder on our SharePoint it is working perfectly fine. Like illustrated here:
[image: <code>Library</code> > <code>Open with Explorer</code>]

A Windows Explorer window gets opened an showing all items. If the user creates an shortcut to this location (e.g. add it to the Windows favorites or on its Desktop) the link is working as well. - all good so far -
The properties will look something like this:
[image: properties of link]

The strange behavior appears after restarting the workstation: The links are not working anymore showing the following error message, that the path is not found:
[image: error message]

Ok seems like the link is broken, but somehow if the user goes back to the SharePoint portal and uses the `Library` > `Open with Explorer` feature on **any** various folder **all** other shortcuts starts working again (till the next restart).

This is obvious kinda unproductive so I'm looking for an solution for this workaround. Any suggestions to solve this?

Comment: user2798895. I've been having completely the same problem for couple of months. Still couldn't find any solution. Did you succeed to find any? If yes, please share. Thanks in advance.

Comment: unfortunately not. But I think its chaued by some authentication problem. The `The network path was not found` Error seams to be some kind of `access denied (due to no "session")`. But I'm just guessing

Answer (score 1):

I just had that problem and it was due to the Web Client service not starting up at boot. This is an old post I just realized, but thought I'd add how I fixed it.

Type in 'services' from the start menu of Windows, which should bring up the local services. Look for the WebClient entry - mine was set to manual - change it to automatic.